# passing constructor to a method set

Tags: java

I don't have a problem, just a doubt.

I did not understand the line `setLayout(new Flowlayout);`

I am thinking that `new FlowLayout()` is a constructor right?
And `setLayou`t is method from `JFrame`.

So we are a able to pass a constructor to the method?
If yes, how can I make my method to accept constructor?

As shown in the code below:

```
package pack;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class frame {    

    public static void main(String args[])
    {           
        JTextField item =new JTextField("i am a text field");
        JFrame j =new JFrame("this is title");
        j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        j.add(item);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what i understand now by your answers is . the code "new FlowLayout()" will create an instance called "in-line" and at the same time the "FlowLayout()" will assign a Layoutmanager to that instance and since it is in argument method brackets it will be passed as a parameter to the method setlayout. is it right?   thank you for your help and i wo nt use   abbreviations again here . thanx for mentioning :)

Answer (score 6):

You are not passing a *constructor* into a method, but rather you are passing an **object**. You create the object "in-line" in the method parameter.

This:

```
j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

and this:

```
FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
j.setLayout(flowLayout);
```

are exactly the same.

---

One word of unasked for advice:  Please avoid unnecessary abbreviations in your posts here.  I recommend this for several reasons:

1. Programming is an exercise in precision.  When you communicate here (or anywhere) about programming issues and questions, you want this communication to be as clear as possible to avoid any chance for ambiguity.   I'd say at least half the answers here are requests for clarification.  Let's avoid that.
2. For many here, English is not their first (or second or third) language.  It's hard enough for them to understand what people are posting here much less if it's couched in obscure and non-standard abbreviations.
3. Extra letters don't cost anything here, so you might as well use them.
4. Using standard English makes your question appear more professional.

Answer (score 0):

`FlowLayout()` is indeed the constructor for the `FlowLayout` class.

But when you use `new FlowLayout()`, you are creating a new `FlowLayout` **object**, and passing it as an argument to the method `setLayout()`.

You are essentially passing an instance of `FlowLayout` to the JFrame in this case, and **not** making it "*accept a constructor*" per se.

Comment: what i understand now by your answers is . the code "new FlowLayout()" will create an instance called "in-line" and at the same time the "FlowLayout()" will assign a Layoutmanager to that instance and since it is in argument method brackets it will be passed as a parameter to the method setlayout. is it right?   thank you for your help and i wo nt use   abbreviations again here . thanx for mentioning :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then no. You can pass an instance of a `class` to a method. In this case, [`JFrame.setLayout(LayoutManager)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29) which takes an instance of a `LayoutManager`. You create one with `new FlowLayout()`. In this case, your code is like

```
LayoutManager anInstance = new FlowLayout();
j.setLayout(anInstance);
```

Comment: what i understand now by your answers is . the code "new FlowLayout()" will create an instance called "in-line" and at the same time the "FlowLayout()" will assign a Layoutmanager to that instance and since it is in argument method brackets it will be passed as a parameter to the method setlayout. is it right?   thank you for your help and i wo nt use   abbreviations again here . thanx for mentioning :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this answer doesn't make sense, but I may be misinterpreting your abbreviations.

Yes any time you use the `new` keyword you are constructing an object.

In your code you are passing a FlowLayout, but from my reading the `.setLayout()` accepts a LayoutManager

Comment: what i understand now by your answers is . the code "new FlowLayout()" will create an instance called "in-line" and at the same time the "FlowLayout()" will assign a Layoutmanager to that instance and since it is in argument method brackets it will be passed as a parameter to the method setlayout. is it right?   thank you for your help and i wo nt use   abbreviations again here . thanx for mentioning :)